# sampling from list of dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy-ndarray

I have data like the sample below.  It's very large and I would like to sample first 10 items from it.  It looks like a list of dicts, but if I try user_train[:5] I get an error.  I can sample one item at a time like user_train[4] works.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

code:

```
user_train[0]
```

output:

```
[{u'asin': u'B00APT3MHO',
  u'helpful': [0, 0],
  u'overall': 5.0,
  'productid': 1,
  u'reviewText': u"Good for someone who likes skinny jeans but doesn't look great in the legging-tight ones. A little stretchy. Not super tight in the knee or ankle, but snug on the thigh and calf.",
  u'reviewTime': u'11 17, 2013',
  u'reviewerID': u'A1JWX45KHE34AL',
  u'reviewerName': u'varnienarsil',
  u'summary': u'Love these jeans',
  u'unixReviewTime': 1384646400},
 {u'asin': u'B00CJ5NH36',
  u'helpful': [0, 0],
  u'overall': 5.0,
  'productid': 2,
  u'reviewText': u"This shirt with it's bold graphic is seriously adorable. I have pretty narrow shoulders, and like the way the sleeves slope off them. The shirt fits loosely in a way that is flattering and I liked the length. I'm no model, but the shirt looks on me as great as it looks in the photo.",
  u'reviewTime': u'11 17, 2013',
  u'reviewerID': u'A1JWX45KHE34AL',
  u'reviewerName': u'varnienarsil',
  u'summary': u'As cute as it looks',
  u'unixReviewTime': 1384646400},
 {u'asin': u'B00F9NGAPM',
  u'helpful': [1, 1],
  u'overall': 3.0,
  'productid': 4,
  u'reviewText': u"The shirt is a little flowy-er than I expected. I like the way it drapes, but the arms are a bit loose (and on me, short&#8212;I'm pretty tall). Has a sort of after-yoga feel rather than the urban feel I was looking for. Super comfortable.",
  u'reviewTime': u'11 17, 2013',
  u'reviewerID': u'A1JWX45KHE34AL',
  u'reviewerName': u'varnienarsil',
  u'summary': u"Like, don't love",
  u'unixReviewTime': 1384646400}]



Update:

code:

user_train[:5]

error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-bb27c2e9fa75> in <module>()
----> 1 user_train[:5]

TypeError: unhashable type
```

Comment: So...., what kind of error do you get? And if you want help with problems with list slices it'd be good if you could provide the list in question.

Comment: @figbeam Thank you for getting back to me so quickly.  I've updated the original post with the error.  Do you have an idea how I could subset user_train to get the first 5 elements?

Comment: Is `user_train` list of lists, or is it a list of dicts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to find a way around it. You could go:

`sample = [user_train[x] for x in range(10)]`

This is called a list comprehension, unhashable type error is usually due to trying to convert a dict to a list.

Comment: thank you, that worked.  However if I do type(user_train) I get a dict, and if I do type(sample) I get a list.  If I inspect the first elements of either one they're identical.